# NameError in Controller#index uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

I am a beginer and I just created a welcomes controller and model welcome with title:string and name:text, and when I run to check does it work or not I get this error which I don't understand since it is very basic code! I should get at least a blank page not error!

```
 views/welcome/index.html.erb

  <h1>Welcomes#index</h1>

  <%= @welcomes.each do |f| %>
  <%= f.title %>
  <%= f.name %>
 <% end %>
```

controllers/welcomes/

```
 class WelcomesController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @welcomes=Welcome.All
 end

 def show
 end

 def create
 end
end
```

the error I get :

```
  NoMethodError in WelcomesController#index

  undefined method 'All' for #<Class:0x007f8bb2af5060>


     class WelcomesController < ApplicationController
      def index
       @welcomes=Welcome.All
     end
```

Answer (score 1):

Within index action of Welcomes Controller modify:

```
@welcomes = Welcomes.All to 

@welcomes = Welcome.all
```

The model name is Welcome and you are using plural of it within index action which generated the error.

Comment: I did and I get this error:  NoMethodError in WelcomesController#index undefined method `All' for #<Class:0x007f8bb2af5060>

Comment: You should use Welcome.all and not All as method name

Comment: I modified the question above and added Welcome.all, and get the new error undefined 'All'.

Comment: Try refreshing your page or do a fresh start. You should get rid of this error now.

Comment: I refreshed but still same issue is there.

Comment: I think my problem was related to 's' at the end of controller, I just made another controller and model with same name but without plural names, and it works fine now. By the way thanks for your helps :)

Comment: In general when we create a model in Rails the name of model is always singular and controller's name is taken as plural by default. And the name of folder in views is also plural. Here the name of your controller is Welcomes but the name of folder in views folder is welcome, which may create some ambiguity.  You can also keep the name of your controller singular depending on the behavior you want. For e.g. your model name is Dashboard so it will be weird to keep your controller name as Dashboards. But make sure the folder name in views folder also matches that, else you can get an error.